# cassandra cql consistency during cas operations

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cassandra-2.0

We want to use check and set operations, but we don't want to allow it to propagate out of our data centre.  The use case is that we want to allow addition of new users in one data centre only, but we want their data to be accessible for read purposes from other data centres. For this we would like to perform a CAS operation with LOCAL QUORUM AND LOCAL SERIAL read.

This issue relates to our problem:[Cassandra: DC Local CAS](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5797)

It looks like the issue has been addressed/fixed, but I can't find examples of how to test/specify this using CQL.

- Is it possible to specify consistency during a CAS operation in CQL? How?
- If not, what is the consistency used during a CAS in CQL?
- We are using the DataStax C++ currently for programmatic queries. Is this possible from that API?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Statement query = session.prepare("UPDATE a set b=? WHERE key=? IF b=?")
        .bind(newValue, key, oldValue)
        .setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_SERIAL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however by CQL I mean CQL from the server shell. Also, I'm asking for an example from the DataStax "C++" API, if possible. I have modified the DataStax driver to incorporate only the changes that I wanted for test purposes... Could not get the CQL SH to do what I wanted.